# whats this in the code?

Tags: assembly, debugging

I m developing a bootloader for which i have a bin file whose assembly is somewhat like this..

```
-u 0 200

141A:0000 CD20          INT 20                                 
141A:0002 FF9F009A      CALL    FAR [BX+9A00]                      
141A:0006 EE            OUT DX,AL                              
141A:0007 FE1D          CALL    FAR [DI]                           
141A:0009 F0            LOCK                                       
141A:000A 4F            DEC DI                                 
141A:000B 037E0E        ADD DI,[BP+0E]                         
141A:000E 8A03          MOV AL,[BP+DI]                         
141A:0010 7E0E          JLE 0020                               
141A:0012 17            POP SS                                 
141A:0013 037E0E        ADD DI,[BP+0E]                         
141A:0016 2904          SUB [SI],AX                            
141A:0018 0304          ADD AX,[SI]                            
141A:001A 0100          ADD [BX+SI],AX                         
141A:001C 02FF          ADD BH,BH                              
141A:001E FFFF          ??? DI                                 
141A:0020 FFFF          ??? DI                                 
141A:0022 FFFF          ??? DI                                 
141A:0024 FFFF          ??? DI                                 
141A:0026 FFFF          ??? DI                                 
141A:0028 FFFF          ??? DI                                 
141A:002A FFFF          ??? DI                                 
141A:002C E40D          IN  AL,0D                              
141A:002E 4E            DEC SI                                 
141A:002F 013E1314      ADD [1413],DI                          
141A:0033 0018          ADD [BX+SI],BL                         
141A:0035 001A          ADD [BP+SI],BL                         
141A:0037 14FF          ADC AL,FF                              
141A:0039 FFFF          ??? DI                                 
141A:003B FF00          INC WORD PTR [BX+SI]                   
141A:003D 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:003F 0005          ADD [DI],AL                            
141A:0041 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:0043 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:0045 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:0047 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:0049 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:004B 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:004D 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:004F 00CD          ADD CH,CL                              
141A:0051 21CB          AND BX,CX                              
141A:0053 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
...                        
141A:007F 0001          ADD [BX+DI],AL                         
141A:0081 200D          AND [DI],CL                            
141A:0083 65            DB  65                                 
141A:0084 726E          JB  00F4                               
141A:0086 65            DB  65                                 
141A:0087 6C            DB  6C                                 
141A:0088 2E            CS:                                    
141A:0089 62            DB  62                                 
141A:008A 69            DB  69                                 
141A:008B 6E            DB  6E                                 
141A:008C 200D          AND [DI],CL                            
141A:008E 204935        AND [BX+DI+35],CL                      
141A:0091 204431        AND [SI+31],AL                         
141A:0094 205033        AND [BX+SI+33],DL                      
141A:0097 3330          XOR SI,[BX+SI]                         
141A:0099 205433        AND [SI+33],DL                         
141A:009C 0D742E        OR  AX,2E74                            
141A:009F 65            DB  65                                 
141A:00A0 7865          JS  0107                               
141A:00A2 0D0000        OR  AX,0000                            
141A:00A5 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:00A7 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:00A9 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:00AB 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
....                         

141A:00FB 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:00FD 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:00FF 00B8C007      ADD [BX+SI+07C0],BH                    
141A:0103 8ED8          MOV DS,AX                              
141A:0105 8EC0          MOV ES,AX                              
141A:0107 BE4F00        MOV SI,004F                            
141A:010A E8E800        CALL    01F5                               
141A:010D BE8F00        MOV SI,008F                            
141A:0110 E8E200        CALL    01F5                               
141A:0113 BFB500        MOV DI,00B5                            
141A:0116 E8E800        CALL    0201                               
141A:0119 BEB500        MOV SI,00B5                            
141A:011C 803C00        CMP BYTE PTR [SI],00                   
141A:011F 74EC          JZ  010D                               
141A:0121 BEB500        MOV SI,00B5                            
141A:0124 BF9100        MOV DI,0091                            
141A:0127 E81C01        CALL    0246                               
141A:012A 7213          JB  013F                               
141A:012C BEB500        MOV SI,00B5                            
141A:012F BF9400        MOV DI,0094                            
141A:0132 E81101        CALL    0246                               
141A:0135 7210          JB  0147                               
141A:0137 BE7800        MOV SI,0078                            
141A:013A E8B800        CALL    01F5                               
141A:013D EBCE          JMP 010D                               
141A:013F BE6300        MOV SI,0063                            
141A:0142 E8B000        CALL    01F5                               
141A:0145 EBC6          JMP 010D                               
141A:0147 BE9900        MOV SI,0099                            
141A:014A E8A800        CALL    01F5                               
141A:014D EBBE          JMP 010D                               
141A:014F 57            PUSH    DI                                 
141A:0150 65            DB  65                                 
141A:0151 6C            DB  6C                                 
141A:0152 63            DB  63                                 
141A:0153 6F            DB  6F                                 
141A:0154 6D            DB  6D                                 
141A:0155 65            DB  65                                 
141A:0156 20746F        AND [SI+6F],DH                         
141A:0159 204D79        AND [DI+79],CL                         
141A:015C 204F53        AND [BX+53],CL                         
141A:015F 210D          AND [DI],CX                            
141A:0161 0A00          OR  AL,[BX+SI]                         
141A:0163 48            DEC AX                                 
141A:0164 65            DB  65                                 
141A:0165 6C            DB  6C                                 
141A:0166 6C            DB  6C                                 
141A:0167 6F            DB  6F                                 
141A:0168 204F53        AND [BX+53],CL                         
141A:016B 44            INC SP                                 
141A:016C 65            DB  65                                 
141A:016D 7620          JBE 018F                               
141A:016F 57            PUSH    DI                                 
141A:0170 6F            DB  6F                                 
141A:0171 726C          JB  01DF                               
141A:0173 64            DB  64                                 
141A:0174 210D          AND [DI],CX                            
141A:0176 0A00          OR  AL,[BX+SI]                         
141A:0178 42            INC DX                                 
141A:0179 61            DB  61                                 
141A:017A 64            DB  64                                 
141A:017B 20636F        AND [BP+DI+6F],AH                      
141A:017E 6D            DB  6D                                 
141A:017F 6D            DB  6D                                 
141A:0180 61            DB  61                                 
141A:0181 6E            DB  6E                                 
141A:0182 64            DB  64                                 
141A:0183 20656E        AND [DI+6E],AH                         
141A:0186 7465          JZ  01ED                               
141A:0188 7265          JB  01EF                               
141A:018A 64            DB  64                                 
141A:018B 2E            CS:                                    
141A:018C 0D0A00        OR  AX,000A                            
141A:018F 3E            DS:                                    
141A:0190 006869        ADD [BX+SI+69],CH                      
141A:0193 006865        ADD [BX+SI+65],CH                      
141A:0196 6C            DB  6C                                 
141A:0197 7000          JO  0199                               
141A:0199 4D            DEC BP                                 
141A:019A 7920          JNS 01BC                               
141A:019C 4F            DEC DI                                 
141A:019D 53            PUSH    BX                                 
141A:019E 3A20          CMP AH,[BX+SI]                         
141A:01A0 43            INC BX                                 
141A:01A1 6F            DB  6F                                 
141A:01A2 6D            DB  6D                                 
141A:01A3 6D            DB  6D                                 
141A:01A4 61            DB  61                                 
141A:01A5 6E            DB  6E                                 
141A:01A6 64            DB  64                                 
141A:01A7 733A          JNB 01E3                               
141A:01A9 206869        AND [BX+SI+69],CH                      
141A:01AC 2C20          SUB AL,20                              
141A:01AE 68            DB  68                                 
141A:01AF 65            DB  65                                 
141A:01B0 6C            DB  6C                                 
141A:01B1 700D          JO  01C0                               
141A:01B3 0A00          OR  AL,[BX+SI]                         
141A:01B5 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01B7 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01B9 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01BB 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01BD 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01BF 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01C1 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01C3 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01C5 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01C7 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01C9 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01CB 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01CD 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01CF 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01D1 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01D3 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01D5 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01D7 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01D9 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01DB 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01DD 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01DF 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01E1 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01E3 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01E5 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01E7 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01E9 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01EB 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01ED 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01EF 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01F1 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01F3 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01F5 AC            LODSB                                      
141A:01F6 08C0          OR  AL,AL                              
141A:01F8 7406          JZ  0200                               
141A:01FA B40E          MOV AH,0E                              
141A:01FC CD10          INT 10                                 
141A:01FE EBF5          JMP 01F5                               
141A:0200 C3            RET
```

AND FOR 100 TO 200

```
-u 100 200

141A:0100 B8C007        MOV AX,07C0                            
141A:0103 8ED8          MOV DS,AX                              
141A:0105 8EC0          MOV ES,AX                              
141A:0107 BE4F00        MOV SI,004F                            
141A:010A E8E800        CALL    01F5                               
141A:010D BE8F00        MOV SI,008F                            
141A:0110 E8E200        CALL    01F5                               
141A:0113 BFB500        MOV DI,00B5                            
141A:0116 E8E800        CALL    0201                               
141A:0119 BEB500        MOV SI,00B5                            
141A:011C 803C00        CMP BYTE PTR [SI],00                   
141A:011F 74EC          JZ  010D                               
141A:0121 BEB500        MOV SI,00B5                            
141A:0124 BF9100        MOV DI,0091                            
141A:0127 E81C01        CALL    0246                               
141A:012A 7213          JB  013F                               
141A:012C BEB500        MOV SI,00B5                            
141A:012F BF9400        MOV DI,0094                            
141A:0132 E81101        CALL    0246                               
141A:0135 7210          JB  0147                               
141A:0137 BE7800        MOV SI,0078                            
141A:013A E8B800        CALL    01F5                               
141A:013D EBCE          JMP 010D                               
141A:013F BE6300        MOV SI,0063                            
141A:0142 E8B000        CALL    01F5                               
141A:0145 EBC6          JMP 010D                               
141A:0147 BE9900        MOV SI,0099                            
141A:014A E8A800        CALL    01F5                               
141A:014D EBBE          JMP 010D                               
141A:014F 57            PUSH    DI                                 
141A:0150 65            DB  65                                 
141A:0151 6C            DB  6C                                 
141A:0152 63            DB  63                                 
141A:0153 6F            DB  6F                                 
141A:0154 6D            DB  6D                                 
141A:0155 65            DB  65                                 
141A:0156 20746F        AND [SI+6F],DH                         
141A:0159 204D79        AND [DI+79],CL                         
141A:015C 204F53        AND [BX+53],CL                         
141A:015F 210D          AND [DI],CX                            
141A:0161 0A00          OR  AL,[BX+SI]                         
141A:0163 48            DEC AX                                 
141A:0164 65            DB  65                                 
141A:0165 6C            DB  6C                                 
141A:0166 6C            DB  6C                                 
141A:0167 6F            DB  6F                                 
141A:0168 204F53        AND [BX+53],CL                         
141A:016B 44            INC SP                                 
141A:016C 65            DB  65                                 
141A:016D 7620          JBE 018F                               
141A:016F 57            PUSH    DI                                 
141A:0170 6F            DB  6F                                 
141A:0171 726C          JB  01DF                               
141A:0173 64            DB  64                                 
141A:0174 210D          AND [DI],CX                            
141A:0176 0A00          OR  AL,[BX+SI]                         
141A:0178 42            INC DX                                 
141A:0179 61            DB  61                                 
141A:017A 64            DB  64                                 
141A:017B 20636F        AND [BP+DI+6F],AH                      
141A:017E 6D            DB  6D                                 
141A:017F 6D            DB  6D                                 
141A:0180 61            DB  61                                 
141A:0181 6E            DB  6E                                 
141A:0182 64            DB  64                                 
141A:0183 20656E        AND [DI+6E],AH                         
141A:0186 7465          JZ  01ED                               
141A:0188 7265          JB  01EF                               
141A:018A 64            DB  64                                 
141A:018B 2E            CS:                                    
141A:018C 0D0A00        OR  AX,000A                            
141A:018F 3E            DS:                                    
141A:0190 006869        ADD [BX+SI+69],CH                      
141A:0193 006865        ADD [BX+SI+65],CH                      
141A:0196 6C            DB  6C                                 
141A:0197 7000          JO  0199                               
141A:0199 4D            DEC BP                                 
141A:019A 7920          JNS 01BC                               
141A:019C 4F            DEC DI                                 
141A:019D 53            PUSH    BX                                 
141A:019E 3A20          CMP AH,[BX+SI]                         
141A:01A0 43            INC BX                                 
141A:01A1 6F            DB  6F                                 
141A:01A2 6D            DB  6D                                 
141A:01A3 6D            DB  6D                                 
141A:01A4 61            DB  61                                 
141A:01A5 6E            DB  6E                                 
141A:01A6 64            DB  64                                 
141A:01A7 733A          JNB 01E3                               
141A:01A9 206869        AND [BX+SI+69],CH                      
141A:01AC 2C20          SUB AL,20                              
141A:01AE 68            DB  68                                 
141A:01AF 65            DB  65                                 
141A:01B0 6C            DB  6C                                 
141A:01B1 700D          JO  01C0                               
141A:01B3 0A00          OR  AL,[BX+SI]                         
141A:01B5 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01B7 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01B9 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01BB 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01BD 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01BF 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01C1 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01C3 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01C5 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01C7 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01C9 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01CB 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01CD 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01CF 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01D1 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01D3 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01D5 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01D7 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01D9 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01DB 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01DD 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01DF 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01E1 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01E3 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01E5 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01E7 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01E9 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01EB 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01ED 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01EF 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01F1 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01F3 0000          ADD [BX+SI],AL                         
141A:01F5 AC            LODSB                                      
141A:01F6 08C0          OR  AL,AL                              
141A:01F8 7406          JZ  0200                               
141A:01FA B40E          MOV AH,0E                              
141A:01FC CD10          INT 10                                 
141A:01FE EBF5          JMP 01F5                               
141A:0200 C3            RET
```

I need to burn this code but my original code lies in between 100 & 200..

- so is that the headers of windows that lie in 0 to 100.
- how should i burn this code so to remove these headers??
- Please Explain if u can?

the ds is somewhat:-

-d 0 200

```
141A:0000  CD 20 FF 9F 00 9A EE FE-1D F0 4F 03 7E 0E 8A 03   . ........O.~...
141A:0010  7E 0E 17 03 7E 0E 29 04-03 04 01 00 02 FF FF FF   ~...~.).........
141A:0020  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF-FF FF FF FF E4 0D 4E 01   ..............N.
141A:0030  3E 13 14 00 18 00 1A 14-FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00   >...............
141A:0040  05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
141A:0050  CD 21 CB 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 20 20 20   .!...........   
141A:0060  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20-00 00 00 00 00 20 20 20           .....   
141A:0070  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00           ........
141A:0080  01 20 0D 65 72 6E 65 6C-2E 62 69 6E 20 0D 20 49   . .ernel.bin . I
141A:0090  35 20 44 31 20 50 33 33-30 20 54 33 0D 74 2E 65   5 D1 P330 T3.t.e
141A:00A0  78 65 0D 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   xe..............
141A:00B0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
141A:00C0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
141A:00D0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
141A:00E0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
141A:00F0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
141A:0100  B8 C0 07 8E D8 8E C0 BE-4F 00 E8 E8 00 BE 8F 00   ........O.......
141A:0110  E8 E2 00 BF B5 00 E8 E8-00 BE B5 00 80 3C 00 74   .............<.t
141A:0120  EC BE B5 00 BF 91 00 E8-1C 01 72 13 BE B5 00 BF   ..........r.....
141A:0130  94 00 E8 11 01 72 10 BE-78 00 E8 B8 00 EB CE BE   .....r..x.......
141A:0140  63 00 E8 B0 00 EB C6 BE-99 00 E8 A8 00 EB BE 57   c..............W
141A:0150  65 6C 63 6F 6D 65 20 74-6F 20 4D 79 20 4F 53 21   elcome to My OS!
141A:0160  0D 0A 00 48 65 6C 6C 6F-20 4F 53 44 65 76 20 57   ...Hello OSDev W
141A:0170  6F 72 6C 64 21 0D 0A 00-42 61 64 20 63 6F 6D 6D   orld!...Bad comm
141A:0180  61 6E 64 20 65 6E 74 65-72 65 64 2E 0D 0A 00 3E   and entered....>
141A:0190  00 68 69 00 68 65 6C 70-00 4D 79 20 4F 53 3A 20   .hi.help.My OS: 
141A:01A0  43 6F 6D 6D 61 6E 64 73-3A 20 68 69 2C 20 68 65   Commands: hi, he
141A:01B0  6C 70 0D 0A 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   lp..............
141A:01C0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
141A:01D0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
141A:01E0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
141A:01F0  00 00 00 00 00 AC 08 C0-74 06 B4 0E CD 10 EB F5   ........t.......
141A:0200  C3                                                .
```

Comment: ...and i thought my brain was sizzling before i saw this...

Comment: @rownage:-dont worry u needn't read whole code ,only i want to know about header and body...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no headers; this is DOS `DEBUG.COM` faking memory so that addresses 0000 to 0100 match the DOS program segment prefix.

If you look at your file in a hex editor then you should see that the first bytes are `B8 C0 07...`.

Comment: thanks a lot...
that means its just a binaryfile with startup from 0100??

Comment: It's just a binary file. When `DEBUG.COM` loads a binary file, it assumes that the startup address is 0100. As your file is a boot loader, it won't contain a startup address, because the BIOS always loads it at a fixed address (07C0:0000).